# Socket.io: Error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting at Socket.emit

Tags: android, node.js, sockets, callback, ack

I successed to send ack to android client from nodejs server but I don't succeed to do reverse. I have this error: Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting  at Socket.emit

Serveur nodejs:

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', data, callThis); 
//this function is executed when client calls it
 function callThis (dataFromClient){
console.log("Call back fired: " + dataFromClient);
 }
```

client android:

```
   socket.on("message", new Emitter.Listener() {

            @Override
            public void call(Object... args) {

                Ack ack = (Ack) args[args.length - 1];
                ack.call();

                JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                .....

   }
}
```

What can I do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Basically support the answer of @Xeoncross. When a connection came, just saved the socket into a map, like below

```js
this.connections = new Map<string, SocketIO.Socket>()
this.server.on("connection", (socket: SocketIO.Socket) => {
      this.connections.set(socket.id, socket)
})
```

Then use a loop to send all users individually

```
public broadcast(msg: string) {
   for(const socket of this.connections.values()) {
        socket.emit("block", msg, (confirm: string) => {
             console.log("confirmation msg: ", confirm)
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, "Callbacks are not supported when broadcasting". It doesn't look like you are broadcasting though, as you are trying to send to a single client. So assuming `socket` is an actual `client` socket instance you can change your code:

```
socket.broadcast.to(socketid).emit('message', data, callThis);
```

to just send to that one person

```
socket.emit('message', data, callThis);
```